# OpenGL segfault in DrawElements

Tags: opengl, c++, sdl

I've asked this question on regular StackOverflow but without much success yet. The below program produces a segfault on the call to `glDrawElements`. I've looked at my max and min index values and they do not go over the length of `GLushort` and match up to the size of my vertex array. I don't get the segfault if I use a smaller number of rings and sectors for my sphere; but I don't think this has much to do with it.

As far as I can tell I've loaded by buffers correctly; however I'm new to OpenGL and this is such a simple program that I must be doing something simple wrong.

I've tried using GLIntercept but it doesn't give me anything additional

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

#include <utilities.hpp>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/sdl.h>
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

struct VertexData
{
    GLdouble position[4];
    GLfloat color[3];
    GLfloat normal[3];
    GLfloat tcoords[2];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_GLContext context;
        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("unable to initialise video");

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 4);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 4);

        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SpaceEngine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        800, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(!window)
            throw std::runtime_error("unable to create window");

        context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

        SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

        GLenum glewErr = glewInit();
        if(glewErr != GLEW_OK)
        {
            SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            throw std::runtime_error(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glewGetErrorString(glewErr)));
        }

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

        std::vector<VertexData> vertices;
        std::vector<GLushort> indices;
        int rings = 200;
        int sectors = 200;
        float radius = 1.0;

        if(rings < 2)
            rings = 2;
        if(sectors < 2)
            sectors = 2;
        while(rings * sectors >= std::numeric_limits<GLushort>::max())
        {
            rings /= 2;
            sectors /= 2;
        }

        const GLuint polyCountXPitch = rings+1;

        GLuint level = 0;

        for(GLuint p1 = 0; p1 < sectors-1; ++p1)
        {
            for(GLuint p2 = 0; p2 < rings-1; ++p2)
            {
                GLuint curr = level + p2;
                indices.push_back(curr + polyCountXPitch);
                indices.push_back(curr);
                indices.push_back(curr + 1);
                indices.push_back(curr + polyCountXPitch);
                indices.push_back(curr + 1);
                indices.push_back(curr + 1 + polyCountXPitch);
            }

            indices.push_back(level + rings - 1 + polyCountXPitch);
            indices.push_back(level + rings - 1);
            indices.push_back(level + rings);

            indices.push_back(level + rings - 1 + polyCountXPitch);
            indices.push_back(level + rings);
            indices.push_back(level + rings + polyCountXPitch);

            level += polyCountXPitch;
        }

        const GLuint polyCountSq = polyCountXPitch * sectors;           //top point
        const GLuint polyCountSq1 = polyCountSq + 1;                    //bottom point
        const GLuint polyCountSqM1 = (sectors - 1) * polyCountXPitch;   //last rows first index

        for(GLuint p2 = 0; p2 < rings - 1; ++p2)
        {
            indices.push_back(polyCountSq);
            indices.push_back(p2 + 1);
            indices.push_back(p2);

            indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1 + p2);
            indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1 + p2 + 1);
            indices.push_back(polyCountSq1);
        }

        indices.push_back(polyCountSq);
        indices.push_back(rings);
        indices.push_back(rings - 1);

        indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1 + rings - 1);
        indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1);
        indices.push_back(polyCountSq1);

        const GLdouble angleX = 2 * pi() / rings;
        const GLdouble angleY = pi() / sectors;

        GLuint i = 0;
        GLdouble axz;
        GLdouble ay = 0;

        vertices.resize(polyCountXPitch * sectors + 2);
        for(GLuint y = 0; y < sectors; ++y)
        {
            ay += angleY;
            const GLdouble sinay = std::sin(ay);
            axz = 0;

            for(GLuint xz = 0; xz < rings; ++xz)
            {
                const glm::vec3 pos((radius * std::cos(axz) * sinay),radius * std::cos(ay), radius * std::sin(axz) * sinay);
                glm::vec3 normal = pos;
                normal = glm::normalize(normal);

                GLuint tu = 0.5f;
                if(y == 0)
                {
                    if(normal.y != -1.0f && normal.y != 1.0f)
                        tu = std::acos(glm::clamp<GLdouble>(normal.x/sinay, -1.0f, 1.0f)) * 0.5 * (1.0f/pi());
                    if(normal.z < 0.0f)
                        tu = 1 - tu;
                }
                else
                    tu = vertices[i-polyCountXPitch].tcoords[0];

                VertexData v;
                v.color[0] = 1;
                v.color[1] = 1;
                v.color[2] = 1;
                v.position[0] = pos.x;
                v.position[1] = pos.y;
                v.position[2] = pos.z;
                v.position[3] = 1.0f;
                v.normal[0] = normal.x;
                v.normal[1] = normal.y;
                v.normal[2] = normal.z;
                v.tcoords[0] = tu;
                v.tcoords[1] = ay * (1.0f/pi());
                vertices.at(i) = v;

                ++i;
                axz += angleX;
            }

            vertices.at(i) = vertices.at(i - rings);
            vertices.at(i).tcoords[0] = 1.0f;
            ++i;
        }

        VertexData v;
        v.color[0] = 1;
        v.color[1] = 1;
        v.color[2] = 1;
        v.position[0] = 0;
        v.position[1] = radius;
        v.position[2] = 0;
        v.position[3] = 1.0f;
        v.normal[0] = 0;
        v.normal[1] = 1;
        v.normal[2] = 0;
        v.tcoords[0] = 0.5f;
        v.tcoords[1] = 0.0f;
        vertices.at(i) = v;
        ++i;
        v.position[1] = -radius;
        v.normal[1] = -1.0f;
        v.tcoords[1] = 1.0f;
        vertices.at(i) = v;

        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(struct VertexData) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, position));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, color));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, normal));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, tcoords));

        GLuint ibo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        GLuint shader1,shader2;
        std::ifstream file("tutorial2.vert");
        if(!file)
            throw std::runtime_error("The file tutorial2.vert was not opened");
        else
        {
            std::string fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

            shader1 = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            std::string fail = "glCreateShader failed using " + GL_VERTEX_SHADER;

            if(!shader1)
                throw std::runtime_error(fail.c_str());

            const GLchar* contents[1];
            contents[0] = fileContents.c_str();
            glShaderSource(shader1, 1, contents, NULL);

            glCompileShader(shader1);
            int compiled;
            glGetShaderiv(shader1, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
            if(compiled == 0)
            {
                int maxLength;
                glGetShaderiv(shader1, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
                char* vertexInfoLog = new char[maxLength];
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader1, maxLength, &maxLength, vertexInfoLog);
                throw std::runtime_error("Shader failed to compile:\n>\t" + std::string(vertexInfoLog));
            }
        }
        std::ifstream file2("tutorial2.frag");
        if(!file2)
            throw std::runtime_error("The file tutorial2.frag was not opened");
        else
        {
            std::string fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file2)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

            shader2 = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            std::string fail = "glCreateShader failed using " + GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
            if(!shader2)
                throw std::runtime_error(fail.c_str());

            const GLchar* contents[1];
            contents[0] = fileContents.c_str();
            glShaderSource(shader2, 1, contents, NULL);

            glCompileShader(shader2);
            int compiled;
            glGetShaderiv(shader2, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
            if(compiled == 0)
            {
                int maxLength;
                glGetShaderiv(shader2, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
                char* vertexInfoLog = new char[maxLength];
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader2, maxLength, &maxLength, vertexInfoLog);
                throw std::runtime_error("Shader failed to compile:\n>\t" + std::string(vertexInfoLog));
            }
        }

        GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
        if(!program)
            throw std::runtime_error("glCreateProgram failed");

        glAttachShader(program, shader1);
        glAttachShader(program, shader2);

        glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "in_Position");
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "in_Color");
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 2, "in_Normal");
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 3, "in_UV");

        glLinkProgram(program);
        int IsLinked;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&IsLinked);
        if(IsLinked == 0)
        {
           int maxLength;
           glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
           char* shaderProgramInfoLog = new char[maxLength];
           glGetProgramInfoLog(program, maxLength, &maxLength, shaderProgramInfoLog);
           throw std::runtime_error("Program failed to link:\n>\t" + std::string(shaderProgramInfoLog) + "");
        }

        glDetachShader(program, shader1);
        glDetachShader(program, shader2);

        bool done = false;

        while(!done)
        {
            SDL_Event event;
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                switch(event.type)
                {
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                    switch(event.window.event)
                    {
                    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE:
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glUseProgram(program);

            glBindVertexArray(vao);

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

            glBindVertexArray(0);

            glUseProgram(0);

            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
            }

        glUseProgram(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glDeleteProgram(program);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();

        std::cout << "all good in the hood" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR:\t" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

precision highp float;

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Color;
in vec3 in_Normal;
in vec2 in_UV;

uniform mat4 mvpmatrix;

out vec3 ex_Color;
void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = in_Position;

    ex_Color = in_Color;
}
```

And my Frag shader:

```
#version 150

precision highp float;

in  vec3 ex_Color;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);
}
```

## **EDIT**

I believe the problem is in the way the element array is being setup for the indices.

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(struct VertexData) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, color));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, normal));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, tcoords));

GLuint ibo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

## **EDIT2**

I've even tried outputing a line of text to a file and iterate through each triangle in my indices 1 by 1. If I run it a few times I find the segfault happens at different points in the indices array. The vertex that the index is looking up is within bounds of my vertices array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tt; i+=3)
{
    file << "attempting " << i/3 << std::endl;
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,i,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdlglHandler);
}
```

So this tells me that I'm trying to access a index that is outside of the bounds from what I sent to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` but again, I cannot see the problem.

Comment: Please only show the code that you suspect has the problem.

Comment: @concept3d, thank you for your reply, please see my edit. I've found that I can stop the error by reducing the number of indices used in the `glDrawElements` call, but the number is variable, which tells me I'm not loading them into the buffer correctly. But reviewing the documentation for OpenGL again and again and every tutorial I can find, I do not see the issue in the way it's being populated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in using GL_DOUBLE for the vertices. Changing to GL_FLOAT seems to have done the trick.

You need to use `glVertexAttribLPointer` when using double.

**EDIT**
That is not completely accurate. glVertexAttribLPointer (...) is for double and dvecN vertex attributes, which your shader is not using. To use glVertexAttribLPointer meaningfully would require you to re-write a line in your shader (in dvec4 in_Position)

Comment: That is not completely accurate. `glVertexAttribLPointer (...)` is for `double` and `dvecN` vertex attributes, which your shader is not using. To use `glVertexAttribLPointer` meaningfully would require you to re-write a line in your shader (`in dvec4 in_Position`).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah, yes. Thanks for clearing that up